# Compare decimal numbers in an alphanumeric value without preg_replace - PHP

Tags: php, compare, numeric

Is it possible to compare decimal values for a value that also contains alphanumeric characters without using `preg_replace` or stripping out the non-numeric values?

For instance comparing these 2 decimal values only ( ignoring any letters) with a simple operator like `>`:
`'down0.1.5.3'`
`'down0.1.7.1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var_dump(version_compare('down0.1.5.3', 'down0.1.7.1'));
var_dump(version_compare('down0.1.8.3', 'down0.1.7.1'));
```

[version_compare()](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`strnatcmp()`](http://php.net/strnatcmp). It might do exactly what you are looking for.